# Using awt.Graphics in a method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, paintcomponent

I created a class called Test, most likely where I went wrong.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test extends JPanel {

Graphics grap;
public void sun()
{
    super.paintComponent(grap);
    grap.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    grap.fillOval(0,0,20,20);
}
}
```

As you can see I want to paint a yellow "Oval" in the top left corner of the panel using a method but I did not use a PaintComponent method. Now I try to implement it in my Paint component method which is in a class called Painting.

```
//import...;
public class Painting extends JPanel{

   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      Test test = new Test();

      test.sun();

   }
```

And now i created a main window that will create a panel and display the yellow oval.

```
//import...
public class main extends JFrame{
    public static main(String [] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(new Painting());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(100,100);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

But this does not work. I have a feeling that it is the sun method in test. How would I get this to work? I have looked in all the java books and cant find anything that can help.

Please note that I do not what to add parameters to the method.

Thank You
Tom.

Comment: What is `CelestialDisplayPanel`?

Comment: In `Test`, won't `grap` always be `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points to be noted here:

1. Never call `super.paintComponent` by yourself except within the overriden `paintComponent` method itself.
2. If you want to do some Graphics activities then override the `paintComponent` method and draw graphics over there
3. When you are overriding `paintComponent` method then the first statement within the method should be `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Now, going by all above points your code should now be like this:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {

 public void paintComponent(Graphics grap)
 {
    super.paintComponent(grap);
    grap.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    grap.fillOval(0,0,20,20);
 }
}
```

And your `Painting` class should be like this:

```
public class Painting extends JPanel{
   Test test;
   public Painting()
   {
     test = new Test();
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     add(test);
   }
}
```

Comment: If i want to draw 50 ovals on different places then i would have a problem with extensive code

Comment: You want to draw 50 ovals on different places on same panel?

Comment: Then you can do this on the `Test JPanel` itself.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure you cant paint in a method?

Comment: No, You can't. You should always override paintComponent method. And if some changes are done like changing the coordinates from outside..then call `repaint` , Swing will do everything for you by itself.

Comment: +1 @Tom: Just to be clear, you can pass a valid graphics context, received in `paintComponent()`, as a parameter to another method.

Answer (score 2):

> If i want to draw 50 ovals on different places then i would have a problem with extensive code

Then you would keep a List of the ovals that you want to paint. See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which paints a bunch of Rectangles on a panel. All the code does is loop through the ArrayList to paint the Rectangle. Only a couple of lines of code are required.